# where to write ZF2 form view helpers

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers

I want to write some custom view helpers that can be used universally by all of the forms in each of my modules.  Where should I write the helpers?  How can I write the view_helpers invokables statement in a project-level config file to avoid having to write it in every module.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to put the invokable configuration in one of the module configs, you'll be able to use the view helpers in any module. Nothing is module-specific in ZF2.

Comment: Right on.

I thought it might be worthwhile to document here some ZF2 characteristics I came across before I received this answer:  If helpers of the same name are put into more than one module, ZF2 allows them to be declared in more than one module.config without throwing an error message.  When more than one custom helper with the same name exists, one of the helpers will respond when called, but not necessarily the helper in the module that called it.  I could not determine what made one helper get called before another.

Comment: All the module configs are merged together, so whichever module is loaded last will win out. This allows you to easily override files from 3rd party modules.

Comment: That's good to know.  Does that mean a project could have a master module.config that declares all of the controllers, all the routers, Doctrine configurations, etc?  Is the `'modules' => array( ... )` statement in `application.config` what dictates the order that the modules get loaded in?

Comment: Yes to both questions.